# sql data query try to write

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table t as below:

```
+------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| Acct |   Date   | Totalamount | Totalcost |
+------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|    1 | 1/1/2013 |          10 |         4 |
|    2 | 1/1/2013 |          20 |         4 |
|    3 | 1/2/2013 |          30 |         4 |
|    4 | 1/2/2013 |          40 |         4 |
|    5 | 1/3/2013 |          50 |         4 |
|    6 | 1/4/2013 |          60 |         4 |
|    7 | 1/6/2013 |          70 |         4 |
|    8 | 1/7/2013 |          10 |         4 |
+------+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to get result as below in sql

```
+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|  sum(totalamount)/count(distinct(date))   | sum(Totalamount) | sum(count(distinct(date))   | sum(count(distinct(acct))   |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|   x                                       | x                | x                           | x                           |
|   x                                       | x                | x                           | x                           |
|   x                                       | x                | x                           | x                           |
|   x                                       | x                | x                           | x                           |
|   x                                       | x                | x                           | x                           |
|   x                                       | x                | x                           | x                           |
|   x                                       | x                | x                           | x                           |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Trying to use 
select from (select........ case when 
group by

Comment: Can you include your current query?

Comment: why you stop? the formula already there..

Answer (score 0):

This will result in a single row result:

```
SELECT
      sum(totalamount)/count(distinct date)     
    , sum(Totalamount)    
    , count(distinct date)   
    , count(distinct acct)  
FROM yourtable
```

That sample data would result in: **48.33333333, 290, 6, 8**

There does not appear to be anything to group by that would result in multiple result rows.